# Create a labeling project in Azure Machine Learning using python code

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-machine-learning-service

The GUI in Azure Machine Learning for creating datasets is straight forward. But I have a hard time creating it through python code. I'm using the Python 3.8 Azure ML kernel. Here is the code I have but it's running into a bug and I'm not able to debug it.

```
from azureml.core import Workspace, Dataset
from azureml.contrib.dataset import FileHandlingOption
from azureml.contrib.dataset.labeled_dataset import _LabeledDatasetFactory

# Authenticate and create a workspace object
ws = Workspace.from_config()

# Get a reference to the registered dataset
dataset = Dataset.get_by_name(ws, 'my-registered-dataset')

# Create a labeled dataset factory
labeled_dataset_factory = _LabeledDatasetFactory()

# Create the labeling project
project = labeled_dataset_factory.from_input_data_reference(
    dataset.as_named_input('my_data').as_download(),
    label_column_name='my-label-column',
    file_handling_option=FileHandlingOption.SKIP_DOWNLOAD
)

# Register the labeling project
project.register(ws)
```

I'm receiving this error message:

```
AttributeError: '_LabeledDatasetFactory' object has no attribute 'from_input_data_reference'
```

What attribute should I use here to get this running?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share which document you are referring to for creating a data labeling? Are you using V2 or V1 SDK?

The quickest way from my personal experience is using the Azure Machine Learning Studio to create it as this document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-image-labeling-projects

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing some lines of your code with the following.

Import package:

```
from azureml.contrib.dataset.labeled_dataset import LabeledDatasetFactory
```

Create a labeled dataset factory:

```
labeled_dataset_factory = LabeledDatasetFactory()
```

Create the labeling project using `.from_dataset()` attribute instead of `.from_input_data_reference`:

```
project = labeled_dataset_factory.from_dataset(
    dataset,
    label_column_name='my-label-column',
    file_handling_option=FileHandlingOption.SKIP_DOWNLOAD
)
```